# How to insert geojson data to geometry field in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I want to insert geoJSON to a `geometry` column of a table.
I have already inserted CSV file to the same column following [this](https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=111771662)
tutorial,
I wonder how to insert the geoJSON to any geometry column?
I tried following [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis)
answer but could not get what is going on there.

Comment: If you are getting an error, then share your table structure and some sample data.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an update with the function [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html):

```
UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(json_column);
```

The following example inserts a GeoJSON point into a JSON column and afterwards updates the geometry column with the above mentioned function.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable(
json_column json,
geom geometry);

INSERT INTO mytable (json_column) VALUES ('{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [7.0069, 51.1623]
}'); 

UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(json_column);

SELECT * FROM mytable;

             json_column              |                    geom                    
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 {                                   +| 01010000009E5E29CB10071C400612143FC6944940
     "type": "Point",                +| 
     "coordinates": [7.0069, 51.1623]+| 
 }                                    | 
(1 Zeile)
```